# Visualizing many points in polytope

Tags: data-visualization, convex, geometry

I need an idea for the following visualization problem.

A *convex polytope* is the bounded intersection of finitely many halfspaces. The dimension of a polytope is the dimension of the affine hull spanned by it.

For a given $3$-dimensional polytope a very fine grid of roughly a billion points is generated inside the polytope. Each point has one of 30 properties (sometimes this number is lower, sometimes slightly higher). Points with the same property are grouped into cells. These cells neither look completely wild nor are they overly simple. In fact, each cell is bounded by finitely many (very few in fact) hypersurfaces of degree at most $4$ with integer coefficients. I have not computed these hypersurfaces so far and it is not clear that this is easy to achieve in my case.

Yet, I am interested in visualizing the cell structure of the polytope. The goal of the visualization is to reach a rough understanding of how the cells are disecting the polytope.

Currently I try to visualize this disection by cutting the polytope with twenty $2$-dimensional parallel hyperplanes and by displaying the induced cell structure of each cut. However, this is not only a little bit too coarse but also takes up a lot of space in my write-up.

Do you maybe have any ideas how to improve this visualization?